C++ OpenCV - How to display a resized video frame to ASCII?
I made a program that turns a video into a resized ASCII animation, but the Mat frame only captures a portion of the top left corner of the full video. The depth and channel of the Mat is 0 and 1, accordingly. The program also doesn't work without the at<uchar>, even though the Mat returns as empty?


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

void checkForOpenCV()
{
    if(cv::getCPUTickCount == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "OpenCV is not detected." << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "OpenCV is detected." << '\n';
    }
}

cv::VideoCapture openVid(std::string &filePath)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap{filePath};
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "The file cannot be accessed." << '\n';
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File is accessed." << '\n';
    }

    return cap;
}

char brightness2Ascii(int brightness, std::string asciiCharset)
{
    int index(brightness * asciiCharset.size() / 256);
    return asciiCharset[index];
}

int main()
{
    checkForOpenCV();

    std::string filePath{R"(C:\Users\Harold.DESKTOP-UJ6F4M4\Videos\video.mp4)"};
    cv::VideoCapture cap{openVid(filePath)};

    double fps{cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS)};
    std::cout << fps << '\n';

    int width(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
    int height(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    int aspectRatio{12};
    std::cout << width << " x " << height << '\n';

    std::vector<cv::Mat> totalFrames{};
    cv::Mat frame{};

    int depth{frame.depth()};
    int channels{frame.channels()};

    while(cap.read(frame))
    {
        cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(width / aspectRatio, height / aspectRatio), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
        totalFrames.push_back(frame.clone());
    }
    cap.release();

    
    for(const auto &frame:totalFrames)
    {
        std::string asciiArt{};
        for(int i{0}; i < frame.rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j{0}; j < frame.cols; j++)
            {
                const std::string asciiCharset{" .'-=*%#@"}; // {" .'-=*%#@"} {"@ "}
                int brightness{frame.at<uchar>(i, j)};
                char pixelChar{brightness2Ascii(brightness, asciiCharset)};
                asciiArt += pixelChar;
            }
            asciiArt += '\n';
        }
std::cout << depth << '\n' << channels << '\n';
        std::cout << asciiArt;
        cv::waitKey(fps / 2);

    }

    return 0;
}

I tried creating a separate Mat resizedFrame, as well as declaring a separate width and height for the asciiChar to no avail. Initially, I thought the problem occured from resizing the frame after preloading all of it, but after relocating the resize() in the preloading loop, I'm not so sure anymore.

is it half or a third? show us. -- at<uchar> must match the Mat's element type. what is its depth and number of channels?

Thanks, I updated the post to have more specific information about the problem.

so it's more like a quarter, suggesting that there's some BGRA/RGBA vs. single bytes going on. idk the depth of your source but OpenCV likely turns it into BGR as OpenCV reads the source. access of non-gray Mats is done with at<Vec3b>() (BGR/3-channel).

Please don't add the solution to the question. Post it as an answer below, and press the checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved.

Whoops, thanks for letting me know, the solution is an answer now.

Turns out I needed to convert the frame into a GRAY Mat if I'll use at<uchar> alongside it. I didn't do that because the video was black and white already, but OpenCV turned it into BGR anyway. For non-gray Mats, use at<Vec3b>() instead.
 for(const auto &frame : totalFrames)
 {
 cv::cvtColor(frame, grayFrame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
 cv::resize(grayFrame, grayFrame, cv::Size(2 * width / aspectRatio, height / aspectRatio), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

 std::string asciiArt{};
 for(int i{0}; i < grayFrame.rows; i++)
 {
     for(int j{0}; j < grayFrame.cols; j++)
     {
         const std::string asciiCharset{".'-=*%#@"}; // {" .'-=*%#@"} {"@ "}
         int brightness{grayFrame.at<uchar>(i, j)};
         char pixelChar{brightness2Ascii(brightness, asciiCharset)};
         asciiArt += pixelChar;
     }
     asciiArt += '\n';
 }
 std::cout << asciiArt;
 Sleep(1000 / fps);

}
